# Associative array as object property in PHP (using pthreads)

Tags: php, multithreading, oop, pthreads

I have a associative array type property in my object. Here's the example:

```
class GetInfo {    

    private $domains_ip = array();

    function get_ip($domain)
    {

        print_r($this->domains_ip);
        $ip = gethostbyname($domain);       
        $this->domains_ip[$ip] = $domain;       
        return $ip;      

    }

}

class my_thread extends Thread {

    private $get_info_object;

    function __construct(GetInfo $obj)
    {
        $this->get_info_object = $obj;
    }

    function check_ip($domain)
    {
        echo $this->get_info_object->get_ip($domain);
    }

}
$o = new GetInfo();
$t = new my_thread($o);

$t->check_ip("google.com");
$t->check_ip("pivo.com");
```

But problem is that `$this->domains_ip` value doesn't change. What appropriate construction should I use in order to add value in this type of property. It works fine without passing it to thread object, but I it needed for my task. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetInfo` does not descend from `pthreads` (it is not `Threaded`):

```
$this->get_info_object = $obj;
```

This results in a serial representation of `$obj` being stored as a member of the `Thread`. This results in the members of `GetInfo` being serialized and will have unexpected results.

The solution is to replace your usage of arrays with suitable objects, the following code is for PHP 7 (pthreads v3+):

```
<?php
class GetHostByNameCache extends Threaded {

    public function lookup(string $host) : string {
        return $this->synchronized(function() use($host) {
            if (isset($this->cache[$host])) {
                return $this->cache[$host];
            }

            return $this->cache[$host] = gethostbyname($host);
        });
    }

    private $cache = [];
}

class Test extends Thread {

    public function __construct(GetHostByNameCache $cache, string $host) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->host = $host;
    }

    public function run() {
        var_dump(
            $this->cache->lookup($this->host));
    }

    private $cache;
}

$tests = [];
$cache = new GetHostByNameCache();
$domains = [
    "google.co.uk",
    "google.com",
    "google.co.jp",
    "google.co.in",
    "google.co.ca",
    "google.net"
];

for ($test = 0; $test < count($domains); $test++) {
    $tests[$test] = new Test($cache, $domains[$test]);
    $tests[$test]->start();
}

foreach ($tests as $test)
    $test->join();

var_dump($cache);
?>
```

This will yield something like:

```
string(14) "216.58.198.195"
string(14) "216.58.198.206"
string(14) "216.58.198.195"
string(14) "216.58.198.195"
string(12) "66.196.36.16"
string(14) "216.58.198.196"
object(GetHostByNameCache)#1 (1) {
  ["cache"]=>
  object(Volatile)#2 (6) {
    ["google.co.uk"]=>
    string(14) "216.58.198.195"
    ["google.com"]=>
    string(14) "216.58.198.206"
    ["google.co.jp"]=>
    string(14) "216.58.198.195"
    ["google.co.in"]=>
    string(14) "216.58.198.195"
    ["google.co.ca"]=>
    string(12) "66.196.36.16"
    ["google.net"]=>
    string(14) "216.58.198.196"
  }
}
```

The important things to notice are:

- The cache object is `Threaded`.
- The array that appears to be used in the cache is cast to `Volatile`.
- The `lookup` routine logic is synchronized.

Because `lookup` is synchronized, not more than one thread can perform a lookup at a time, this ensures no two threads can perform the same lookup twice. You might be able to come up with a more efficient way of synchronizing access to the cache (on a per record basis), but this is a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated, now it works just as planned!

Comment: But I have one more question: When I have file handlers as my private propteries I've got this error - PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given. It happens only when class extends Threaded. What could it be? Thanks!

Comment: Resources do not support serialization, nor are they well supported by pthreads. You should avoid trying to share them.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks for claryfing.